# Count number of rows in a column with an entry if that entry is the first entry in the row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking to count the number of rows in a column that have an entry only until that same row has a second entry.  In the example below, that would be a count of the cells in the columns which are not yellow.

See the top row of the included screenshot, or the second, annotated screenshot

**Example data**:

[image: Chart data]

**Annotated**:

[image: Chart data - annotated]

Comment: so what would the output look like?

Comment: It isn't clear where you're counting from, or how many results there would be.

Comment: if you can add a cell for each row, you can use the COUNTA function to find how many cells in the rest of the row have a value and in this case put a 1 in the cell... then it's just a matter of summing the 1s

Comment: I mean a formula like =IF(COUNTA(C1:Z1)>1; 1; 0)

Comment: FWIW looking at the picture makes things a bit clearer: count number of rows with an entry, if the entry on that row is the first entry else ignore and don't count.

Comment: After DavidPostill kindly reopened this Q, I have made a significant edit to try to clarify your intent @DEH. If you feel this goes too far or does not address what you were asking, please feel free to further edit or revert :)

Answer (score 0):

### How can the number of rows in a column with an entry be counted if that entry is the first entry in the row?

**tl;dr**: A separate sheet to get the position of the first piece of data

---

Using a separate sheet with a column for the rows, you could use the formula:

```
=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(Datasheet!B2:Z2),0)
```

Where:

- Datasheet is the name of the sheet with your customer data
- B2:Z2 is the row you want to check

Plus, on the original sheet:

```
=COUNTIF(Find!$A1:$A30,COLUMN(B1)-1)
```

Where:

- Find is the additional sheet with the `=MATCH(...)` formulae
- $A1:$A30 are the cells with the results
- B1 is the first column examined
- `-1` is there because the column index on the search sheet is one higher

### Illustration

Data sheet:

[image: partial data]

Count sheet:

[image: partial data counts]

*(numbers are column indices + 1)*

### Is this possible with a formula in a single sheet?

Probably!